# How to get the content of joomla editor in joomla2.5 iframe Madal box

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a form where I have joomla2.5 Editor. I want to show the content of that joomla2.5 Editor in Iframe Joomla2.5 Modal Box.
I use joomla editor

```
<?php 
  $editor =& JFactory::getEditor(); 
  echo $editor->display( 'body', '', '400', '150', '20', '20', false, $params );
?>
```

This page is in view folder.
I use the code in js file like `window.parent.document.getElementById('body').value or window.parent.jInsertEditorText(tag, this.body);`And it is included in js file. when I try to alert, alert shows null.
How to fix this in js file. If any body knows about it, please, reply it.
I need your hand.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get done here, but this seems like a bad way to do it

Comment: Are you trying to display the editor in a modal window?

Answer (score 2):

> I write the answer here, because the comments are not good to display
>   code

Joomla modal functionality is good to show a link from a component but does not allow us to open a given element on the page. Therefor you need to write your own code, first of all do not override Joomla's core or all the modifications you make will be overriden the next time you upgrade. So assuming that you take this into account:

1- First thing to do, add the javascript code for your custom modal window. You will need to pass the text container div id or classname to the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Main parameters:
    // Modify texteditor-id with the id or classname on your text div. For a classname use '.' instead of '#'
    var HTMLContent = $("#texteditor-id").html();

    var width = 600; 
    var height = 250;

    $('#button').click(function(){
            // transparent background
            // we create a new div, with two attributes
            var bgdiv = $('<div>').attr({
                                    className: 'bgtransparent',
                                    id: 'bgtransparent'
                                    });

            // add the new div to the page
            $('body').append(bgdiv);

            // get the widht and height of the main window
            var wscr = $(window).width();
            var hscr = $(window).height();

            // set the background dimensions
            $('#bgtransparent').css("width", wscr);
            $('#bgtransparent').css("height", hscr);


            // modal window
            // create other div for the modal window and two attributes
            var moddiv = $('<div>').attr({
                                    className: 'bgmodal',
                                    id: 'bgmodal'
                                    });     

            // add div to the page
            $('body').append(moddiv);

            // add HTML content to the modal window
            $('#bgmodal').append(HTMLContent);

            // resize for center adjustment
            $(window).resize();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
            // explorer window dimensions
            var wscr = $(window).width();
            var hscr = $(window).height();

            // setting background dimensions
            $('#bgtransparent').css("width", wscr);
            $('#bgtransparent').css("height", hscr);

            // setting modal window size
            $('#bgmodal').css("width", ancho+'px');
            $('#bgmodal').css("height", alto+'px');

            // getting modal window size
            var wcnt = $('#bgmodal').width();
            var hcnt = $('#bgmodal').height();

            // get central position
            var mleft = ( wscr - wcnt ) / 2;
            var mtop = ( hscr - hcnt ) / 2;

            // setting modal window centered
            $('#bgmodal').css("left", mleft+'px');
            $('#bgmodal').css("top", mtop+'px');
    });

 });

 function closeModal(){
    // remove created divs
    $('#bgmodal').remove();
    $('#bgtransparent').remove();
}
</script>
```

2- Your preview link must look something like this, the most important part is the id="button" part because it will be used to be identified by the previous jquery code:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Preview" />
```

3- Add the following code to your css

```
.bgtransparent{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}

.bgmodal{
    position:fixed; 
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:1em;
    border:0.05em solid black;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

And that is basically what you need to do. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has an inbuilt way to show modal boxes:

First you need to do is ask Joomla to load the modal library:

```
 <?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); ?>
```

And this is the code that opens the modal window:

```
<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 750, y: 600}}" href="url_to_modal_editor" target="_blank"> Open Modal Editor</a>
```

This will go in the linked href page (the page of the modal editor), lets say editor.p:

```
<?php 
  $editor =& JFactory::getEditor(); 
  echo $editor->display( 'body', '', '400', '150', '20', '20', false, $params );  
?>
```

Comment: I need to show the content of joomla2.5 text editor in joomla2.5 popup modal box. How to to do in my js file. I need your hand.Thank you.

Comment: Some questions:
1- In Javascript ? 
2- Do you want it on a click of a button, on the load of a page.. ?
3- The modal must show just the content of the editor or the editor itself ?

Comment: Before saving in database, user can see form's preview in joomla2.5 modal popup box.user have a form and under the form there is a link like preview.After clicking preview link, user can see the form field's preview in joomla2.5 popup modal box.Form's input text is showing in modal box, that's fine. But, Joomla2.5 editor's content is now showing in modal box.Link is given in view tmpl file from where javascript calls in js file. How to get joomla2.5 text editor's content in modal box. How to fix in my js file. I need your hand.

Answer (score 0):

Please include class="modal" in anchor tag.